# Error building frontier-node-template

Tags: frontier, frontier-node-template

I am trying to build the Frontier Node Template from this [code](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/frontier-node-template/) or from the [Frontier repository](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/tree/master/template).

But when running the `cargo build --release` I am getting the following error:

```
 error: non-defining opaque type use in defining scope
 --> /Users/alex/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/evm-0.37.0/src/executor/stack/memory.rs:570:3
    |
570 |         self.substate.deconstruct(self.backend)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime `'config` is part of concrete type but not used in parameter list of the `impl Trait` type alias

  Compiling sp-application-crypto v7.0.0 (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate?branch=master#6376f13a)
  error: could not compile `evm` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to compile it. I am not sure what was causing the error, but this is what I did:

I updated the rust toolchain:

```
rustup update
```

Check i was in the last commit, delete the `Cargo.lock` and:

```
clean cargo
cargo build --release
```

And it worked!